# Symfony3 JWT Authentication with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle drops error on token generation

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I just installed and configured the [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) as the provided example shows for.

But when I try to generate a token

with

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test
```

I use my correct user and password

I get:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Failed to load private key \"\/home\/web\/symfony\/app\/var\/jwt\/private.pem\". Did you correctly configure the corresponding passphrase?
```

How do I debug this error?

Comment: What you want to debug if everything that you need  to know is in the error message? When you created key you set passphrase, and now you should set it in bundle config `pass_phrase` or generate keys without passphrase.

Comment: oopsy! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Please set provider first in app/config/security.yml file like below:-

```
providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users: 
                    johndoe:
                        password: test
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
```

After above setting, you can run below command, after running below command you will get token, use that token for your request:

```
 curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test
```

For more about setting, please refer below link:-
[enter link description here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)